# in linux for named pipe does each new client connection has different buffer ? Does named pipe behave in same way under linux and windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ipc, named-pipes

For windows ==>  All instances of a named pipe share the same pipe name, but each instance has its own buffers and handles, and provides a separate conduit for client/server communication. The use of instances enables multiple pipe clients to use the same named pipe simultaneously.

For linux
I have created a named pipe by my server process.
I want to have multiple clients to be connected to this named pipe, and Each new connection should not interfere with each other, there should be a separate connection for new client.

but when multiple clients are connected to server then is there a separate buffer allocated to each connection like in windows ?

Comment: No, you should use `AF_LOCAL` sockets on Linux

Comment: is named pipe behavior different under windows and linux

Comment: It is different. Linux uses sockets for client-server architecture. This allows you to write app that can work locally and via net. On Windows there are no `AF_LOCAL` sockets, instead they have separate machanism - named pipes.